# Joomla forget menu type of my component

Tags: joomla2.5

I have made a component for Joomla and my (last) trouble is that the parameters cannot be edited.

For instance, I created my menu from the "menu maker", it says that the menu is saved but doesn't show editable parameters. The field menu type is empty so no parameters I have set for my component is showing...

It works nicely on the website.

I have reinstalled Joomla on another database and the same thing happens...

Could someone kindly point me toward right direction ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I had a parameter for "layout" in the "request" fieldset and Joomla seems to be confused with that.

So I renamed the parameter to "myLayout" and used this code in the view.php :

```
$this->setLayout(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('myLayout','null','cmd'))
```

And it works great :)